# MediaPlayer always null Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, media-player

I am trying to play mp3 with url from json that I got it from my api. but when I click to play music it can not play and get error :( I try more and more but .... zero. please help .

This is my source code :

```
public void playRadioTrack(final RadioTrack radio) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>() {
            private String maxDurationText;

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        findViewById(R.id.imgButtonPlay).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        findViewById(R.id.progressLoadingMedia).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRadioName)).setText(radio.getName());
                        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRadioName)).setText("Test thoi ma"); 
                    }
                });
            };

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {  
                if (mPlayer == null) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(radio.getAudioUrl()); 
                MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ScreenHomeActivity.this, uri);
            }
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.reset();
            System.out.println(">>>> BUG >>>>" + radio.getAudioUrl());
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://admega.vn/anhsai.mp3");
            MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ScreenHomeActivity.this, uri);
            mPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

                @Override
                public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                    publishProgress(mp.getDuration(), mp.getCurrentPosition(), percent);
                }
            });
            mPlayer.start(); 
            return null; 
        }

            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                ((SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar)).setMax(values[0]);
                ((SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar)).setProgress(values[1]);
                ((SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar)).setSecondaryProgress(values[2] * values[0] / 100);
                int seconds = (int) (values[1] / 1000) % 60;
                int minutes = (int) ((values[1] / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtProgress)).setText(minutes + ":" + seconds);
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtProgress)).setText("");
            };

            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        findViewById(R.id.imgButtonPlay).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        findViewById(R.id.progressLoadingMedia).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            };
        }.execute();

    }
```

As you see. My player always return null and have error as the image below. 
Images here: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uwsmx.png

I think it have problem with mp3 file, but its not, I change and get new mp3, it's the same.

Comment: Why would you create MediaPlayer inside AsyncTask?

Comment: Just for future reference: onPostExecute already runs on UI thread. No need to specify that explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating it on a non Looper prepared thread, in the **doInBackground** method to be exactly inside your code.

As MediaPlayer docs says:

> In order to receive the respective callback associated with these listeners, applications are required to create MediaPlayer objects on a thread with its own Looper running (main UI thread by default has a Looper running).

Two options, **create MediaPlayers in onPreExecute method**, or **call Looper.prepare() in the first line of your doInBackground method**.